# Undefined boost reference despite correct linking

Tags: c++, boost

I found a lot of similar problems, but I was not able to apply any given solution for me. A few months ago, I worked on a project using the boost library. I compiled simply in the command line, as described on the boost website.

```
g++ -I pathToBoost file.cpp -o file -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem
```

The two required linkings to boost_system and boost_filesystem were also done. This worked perfectly, but now suddenly an error occurs when i tried to compile it again.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccM2BzEo.o: in function `boost::system::generic_category()':
file.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6system16generic_categoryEv[_ZN5boost6system16generic_categoryEv]+0x7): 

undefined reference to `boost::system::detail::generic_category_instance'
```

Well, it seems to me that there is an error linking the boost_system library. Since the same thing worked before, is a problem with the compiler possible?

I used

```
Boost 1.68.0
g++ (GCC) 8.2.1
ManjaroLinux 18.0.3
```

I hope that somebody can help me here and that I was not just too stupid to see a solution in another thread.

Greetings!

Comment: Maybe helpful: [Undefined reference to generic_category_instance](https://github.com/boostorg/system/issues/26)

Answer (score 1):

The order of libraries in linker command line is important. `boost_filesystem` depends on `boost_system`, hence the fix:

```
-lboost_filesystem -lboost_system
```

Alternatively, you can surround the list of libraries with `--start-group` and `--end-group` to make the linker re-scan the libraries multiple times until it either fails or resolves all symbols, so that no specific ordering of libraries in the command line is necessary. However, it may take longer to link. E.g.:

```
g++ -I pathToBoost file.cpp -o file -Wl,--start-group -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -Wl,--end-group
```

---

Since you specify `-I pathToBoost` you also need to specify `-L<path-to-boost-libs> -Wl,-rpath=<path-to-boost-libs>`. Otherwise it uses headers from one version of boost from `pathToBoost`, but links wrong libraries from your system boost.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately the change of the order or using the grouping technique did not work, the error remained the same.. Any idea, what else could cause it?

Comment: Thank you again for your effort. Although that sounds like a reasonable solution, directly linking the libraries did not solve the occurence error. As I stated, the same command worked perfectly a little time ago. I did not really change anything in my system, but could something in that direction have caused it?